# MSSQL Trigger if id exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, triggers

I have problem with MSSQL trigger. I want to create trigger which will be check if id exist in other table and if it will be exist it will not insert a record.

Example
We have Person, Person could be a Student or Teacher, but it can't be the Student and Teacher in the same time. So I need to check before insert and update if Teacher exist with the same id like Student that I trying to insert. I am not sure is this clear?

I try to found answer, I found some triggers but not what I want. Could you help me with this?

I attache UML diagram with my problem:
[UML Diagram](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/527/9c92.png)

With help of **Muhammed Ali** I wrote this:

```
CREATE Trigger tr_TriggerName
ON Student
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
       IF NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT Teacher.id 
            FROM Teacher 
            WHERE Teacher.id = 
            (SELECT inserted.id FROM inserted))         
        BEGIN
            /* This isnert is wrong I don't know how to write it?????*/
            INSERT INTO Student VALUES (inserted.id, inserted.field1, inserted.field2); 
        END
        ELSE
            RAISERROR ('There is already a Teacher with the same Student id', 0, 0);
            RETURN
END
```

This is exactly what I want, but I don't know how to write this insert.

I wrote earlier that Person could be a Student or Teacher, but it can't be a Student and Teacher in the same time. So if I want to insert Student to my table I must check table which Teatchers. If Teacher exist with the same Persson id (like Student that I  try to insert) I must show error message. If (or else..:)) Teacher not exist I need to insert him, but I don't konow how to write this insert in my trigger.

Comment: Why don't you create a type field (say, personTypeId) in person table to mark a person as Teacher or Student. Then a record will be one of them but not both by design. i.e. `Person: PersonTypes => 1:Many relationship`

Comment: I thought about it. But this is task for my studies and my Teacher tell me that the best solution is to use triggers and I want to know for myself how to write trigger like this one.

Comment: Do you want an exception, e.g. using `RaIsError`, if there is a conflict? Your question is a little unclear about performing an `UPDATE` if an `INSERT` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for an alternative:

```
CREATE Trigger tr_TriggerName
ON Student
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

declare @count int
select @count=count(*) from inserted

insert into Student (id,field1,field2)
select id,field1,field2 from inserted
where id not in (select id from teacher)

if @@ROWCOUNT<@count
  raiserror('Some Teachers were rejected due to conflicts with Student ids', 0, 0);

END
```

**EDIT**: I modified it a bit, for the error message to cover partial failure of multiple row insert. In order to display an error *for each rejected `id`*, a cursor should be employed.

Comment: Thank you all for your time spent. This answer enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way, without rewriting INSERT logic, so the same trigger can be used on INSERT and on UPDATE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_StudentNotTeacher
ON Student
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Teacher T
            JOIN inserted i ON i.id=T.id
            WHERE T.id IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Person cannot be Student and Teacher at the same time', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN
END;
```

Need the same (analogous) trigger on Teacher table.